# php curl first request always returns empty

Tags: php, curl

I have a php page **scraper.php** which gives a multiline urls textbox and a button to scrape the urls.

In the page I have code which loops over all nonempty url lines and makes a curl request
for each one, this request is then written to a file and appears as a link in a table at the bottom of page when the requests have been executed.

**problem**

- When there is more than one url the first one always returns an empty response
- Reversing the order of the urls causes the new first one to return empty and the other one now succeeds

I'm testing with following two urls, but behaviour seems to be the same for other urls

1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php
2. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

---

code below =>

**scraper.php**

```
...
<?php
if($_POST["data"] != "")
{
  $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST["data"]);
  echo "<br><table>";
  $ch  = curl_init();
  foreach($lines as $line)
  {
    if($line != "" and strlen($line) > 1)
    {
      $hash = substr(md5($line), 0, 6);
      $time = date("Hi");
      $fname = "file_" . $hash . "_" . $time;
      $lname = "/var/www/html/" . $fname;
      $out = fopen($lname, "w");
      if($out == FALSE)die("failed to open file..");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $line);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
//      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
//      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
//      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
      $output = curl_exec($ch);
      $error = curl_error($ch);
      if($error != "")
      {
        fwrite($out, $error);
      }
      else
      {
        if($output == "")
        {
          $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
//        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $line);
//        $output = curl_exec($ch);
//          $output = $info["total_time"];
          $output = "info: " . print_r($info, true) . "error: " . print_r($error, true) . "line: " . print_r($line, true);
        }
        fwrite($out, $output);
      }
      fclose($out);
      echo "<tr><td>" . $line . "</td>"
         . "<td>" . "<a href=\"./" . $fname . "\">" . $fname . "</a>"
         . "</td></tr>";
    }
  }
  curl_close($ch);
  echo "</table>";
}
?>
...
```

And the output of the print_r line above (including the info, error and line) is

**debug output**

```
info: Array
(
    [url] => https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
    [http_version] => 0
    [protocol] => 0
    [ssl_verifyresult] => 0
    [scheme] => 
    [appconnect_time_us] => 0
    [connect_time_us] => 0
    [namelookup_time_us] => 0
    [pretransfer_time_us] => 0
    [redirect_time_us] => 0
    [starttransfer_time_us] => 0
    [total_time_us] => 0
)
error: line: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
```

---

**notes**

- all the zeros in curl_getinfo like http_code and total_time
- if only one url in textbox (the jsonformatter one from above) then it successfully gets output

Comment: And what is the output of `print_r($error)` and `print_r($line)` for the first request?

Comment: `seem like it didn't even do the request`...so have you done any basic debugging to check that, as suggested above?

Comment: ive edited the question to add the contents of $error and $line above

Comment: You need to test $line just after `foreach($lines as $line)`, so then you can  check it before the `if` condition which could make it skip the curl request.

Comment: @ADyson curl_getinfo executes as posted output shows, this is a nested part of the if statement and shows the if condition is not skipped

Comment: I see. Normally if you get a 0 in the http code field it means the request failed before it could be sent, but that ought to result in curl_error producing output. Very odd. Out of interest, if you put the same URL in the list more than once, does it call it successfully the second time?

Comment: If I put the same url twice at the start, the output is still just the output of the debug curl_getinfo meaning it gets the same empty output twice

Comment: What about if you put the URL 1st and 3rd in the $lines list? Since you said it works if it's called the second time.

Comment: When I put it 1st and 3rd, now the first and second request fail but the 3rd succeeded

Comment: ok so the problem was that there were linefeeds in the url from the textbox, removing these it now seems to work

Comment: I was going to say it doesn't make much sense on the face of it. Can probably just close as a typo then. Glad you fixed it.